# Groupby count per category per month (Current month vs Remaining past months) in separate columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count, pandas-groupby

Lets say I have the following dataframe:

[image: Initial Dataframe]

I am trying to get something like this.

[image: Expected Output]

I was thinking to maybe use the rolling function and have separate dataframes for each count type(current month and past 3 months) and then merge them based on ID.

I am new to python and pandas so please bear with me if its a simple question. I am still learning :)

EDIT:

@furas so I started with calculating cumulative sum for all the counts as separate columns

```
 df['f_count_cum] = df.groupby(["ID"])['f_count'].transform(lambda x:x.expanding().sum())
    df['t_count_cum] = df.groupby(["ID"])['t_count'].transform(lambda x:x.expanding().sum())
```

and then just get the current month df by

```
df_current = df[df.index == (max(df.index)]
df_past_month = df[df.index == (max(df.index - 1)]
```

and then just merge the two dataframes based on the ID ?

I am not sure if its correct but this is my first take on this

Comment: Is the "month" column a date, or a string?

Comment: Best to post your input and expected output as text so that people can copy paste and get started. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @00 "month" column is a date type and index for the dataframe as well

Comment: I just fixed the initial dataframe snapshot as I just noticed it didnt have the full four months  of data

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? It would be much better if you put example data as text in code `df = pd.DataFrame(....)` because then we can use it to test ideas.

Comment: Shouldn't f_count(past 3 months) for 'A' be 13.?

Comment: @Uts thank you, thats exactly what I was looking for, I never thought about the last and first functions. And yes f_count(past 3 months) in the sample should be 13

Comment: @Uts Thanks again for the help, I am having problem, what if I want to get previous 2 months from the current month. The current code get the first 3 months from the start. What if I want to get the two months from the current month. Let me know if that makes sense

Comment: added the condition.

Comment: @Uts thank you again

Comment: Nw, in that case you can upvote the answer by clicking up arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few assumptions looking at the input sample:

1. `Month` index is of `datetime64[ns]` type. If not, please use below to typecast the datatype.

   `df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Month)`
2. `Month` column is the index. If not, please set it as index.

   `df = df.set_index('Month')`
3. Considering last month of the df as current month and first 3 months as 'past 3 months'. If not modify the `last` and `first` function accordingly in df1 and df2 respectively.

**Code**

```
df1 = df.last('M').groupby('ID').sum().reset_index().rename(
    columns={'f_count':'f_count(current month)',
            't_count':'t_count(current month)'})
df2 = df.first('3M').groupby('ID').sum().reset_index().rename(
    columns={'f_count':'f_count(past 3 months)',
            't_count':'t_count(past 3 months)'})

df  = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID', how='inner').reindex(columns = [ 'ID',
    'f_count(current month)', 'f_count(past 3 months)',
    't_count(current month)','t_count(past 3 months)'
])
```

**Output**

```
    ID  f_count(current month)  f_count(past 3 months)  t_count(current month)  t_count(past 3 months)
0   A   3   13  8   14
1   B   3   5   7   5
2   C   1   3   2   4
```

**Another version of same code, if you prefer function and single statement**

```
def get_df(freq):
    if freq=='M': 
        return df.last('M').groupby('ID').sum().reset_index()
    return df.first('3M').groupby('ID').sum().reset_index() 

df = pd.merge(get_df('M').rename(
    columns={'f_count':'f_count(current month)',
         't_count':'t_count(current month)'}),
        get_df('3M').rename(
   columns={'f_count':'f_count(past 3 months)',
            't_count':'t_count(past 3 months)'}),
        on='ID').reindex(columns = [ 'ID',
    'f_count(current month)', 'f_count(past 3 months)',
   't_count(current month)','t_count(past 3 months)'])
```

**EDIT:**

For previous two months from current month:(we can use different combinations of first and last function as per our need)

```
df2 = df.last('3M').first('2M').groupby('ID').sum().reset_index().rename(
    columns={'f_count':'f_count(past 3 months)',
            't_count':'t_count(past 3 months)'})
```